# PayPal doesn't send email and instead fails to place the order

Tags: error, paypal, paypal-express, ce-1.9.1.0, error-log

**See edit below**

I have set up `Express Checkout`, which is mostly working fine. Even the transaction works. However, at the end, it says `Express Checkout cannot be initialized` and there is no mail being sent. Here's the error log:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xxx-xxx.core_email_queue_recipients' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `recips`.`recipient_email`, `recips`.`recipient_name`, `recips`.`email_type` FROM `core_email_queue_recipients` AS `recips`
 INNER JOIN `core_email_queue` AS `queue` ON queue.message_id = recips.message_id WHERE (queue.entity_id ='42' ) AND (queue.entity_type ='order' ) AND (queue.event_type ='new_order' ) AND (queue.message_body_hash ='1e16ff26bc02467cdfe82bfee8912bad' )' in /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php:65371
Stack trace:
#0 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xincludes/src/__default.php(64952): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php(54273): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php(55316): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `recips`...', Array)
#4 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php(56176): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `recips`...', Array)
#5 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php(54530): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Email_Queue.php(89): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Email_Queue->wasEmailQueued(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue))
#8 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template.php(422): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->addMessageToQueue()
#9 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template.php(508): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#10 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('sales_email_ord...', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#11 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order.php(1354): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#12 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn.php(663): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail()
#13 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn.php(622): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->_registerPaymentAuthorization()
#14 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn.php(365): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->_registerPaymentPending()
#15 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn.php(293): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->_registerTransaction()
#16 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn.php(118): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->_processOrder()
#17 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/IpnController.php(43): Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn->processIpnRequest(Array, Object(Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl))
#18 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php(14098): Mage_Paypal_IpnController->indexAction()
#19 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php(18482): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#20 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php(18016): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#21 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/includes/src/__default.php(20808): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#22 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#23 /is/htdocs/wp11057204_2LXPKUVAZP/www/xxx/index.php(92): Mage::run('', 'store')
#24 {main}
```

I have once moved the Magento installation and later updated it to 1.9.1.0, maybe I messed something up while doing that?

Any ideas why this happens or how to solve the problem are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: Ok, the error message tells me I don't have that table, which is indeed the case. I suppose, however, this *should* have been created when I updated to 1.9.1, right?

Why didn't this happen? Can someone give me the structure of the table so that I can manually create it or is there a better solution?

Comment: Have you checked express checkout log by enabling debug mode yes in payment method setting?

Comment: @HardikShah well, the order placement and stuff works, that's why there is not much to see. My issue is that it fails sending the email and therefore says he failed to place the order (even though the money has already been transferred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was quite simple actually:

1. install a new Magento system and
2. export and import the tables `core_email_queue` and `core_email_queue_recipients` to the live system

Somehow, the tables weren't created during my update to 1.9.1. No idea whatsoever why this happened, but it did.